# how can I do this better in javascript: add a pair (key, value) to a hash while iterating?

Tags: javascript, hash, iteration

I wrote this solution that works, although I would like to verify with the community if there is a better way to **add a pair (key, value) to a hash while I am iterating**. I have to create a new function with name `addPairToHashAndReturnIt` as an auxiliar function.

The challenge is the following:

> Create a function `countBy` that accepts an array and a callback, and returns an object. countBy will iterate through the array and perform the callback on each element. Each return value from the callback will be saved as a key on the object. The value associated with each key will be the number of times that particular return value was returned.

```js
function countBy(array, callback) {
  return array.reduce(
    (acc, each) =>
      (!acc[callback(each)] && addPairToHashAndReturnIt(acc, callback(each), each)) ||
      ((acc[callback(each)] += 1) && acc),
    {}
  );
}
    
const addPairToHashAndReturnIt = (hash, key, value) => {
  hash[key] = 1;
  return hash;
};
    
function evenOrOddNumber(num) {
  if (num % 2 === 0) return 'even';
  else return 'odd';
};

console.log(
  countBy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], evenOrOddNumber)
); // should log: { odd: 3, even: 2 }
```

So, what do you think about this solution?

Comment: Does the code work and you're looking for a review? Right away, trying to turn complex conditionals into an expression in your `reduce` looks very suspicious/overly clever to me. The code appears non-working, so instead of asking for "better way"/"what do you think?" I recommend asking "how can I do this correctly?"

Comment: `// should log: { odd: 3, even: 2 }` 
Actually it returns `{ odd: 3, even: 3 }`

Comment: Thank you for the advices! I will reformulate the question.

Comment: Thank you Supid, I fixed the bug. I wasn't initializing the hash with 1. Now is working!

Comment: I understood that I wrote a complex condition in my reduce callback.  I suppose it is more legible to write an if-else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your logic, don't make it unnecessarily complicated.

We aren't wanting to *overwrite* the value of `hash[value]` with `5` (for instance), we're just wanting to *increment* `hash[value]` every time we get a match. The form will look like `hash[value]++`, not `hash[value] = item`.

See also: [Is Reduce() Bad?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnZ7jMFCa4Y)

```js
const evenOrOddNumber = (num) => (num % 2 == 0)
  ? 'even'
  : 'odd';

const countBy = (array, callback) => {
  // store counts
  const counts = {};
  
  array.forEach(item => {
    // store callback result, previous count
    const val = callback(item);
    const prevCount = counts[val] || 0;
    
    // increment count
    counts[val] = prevCount + 1;
  });
  
  return counts;
}

console.log(
  countBy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], evenOrOddNumber)
); // should log: { odd: 3, even: 2 }
```

Comment: Thank you Christian! I fixed the bug! I shouldn't overwrite the value of `hash[key]`, just increment it.

Comment: Also please  `return num % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';`